# Rendering SVGs from HTML with Android browser

Tags: android, html, ios, safari, svg

I've been searching and have not really found a good solution for rendering SVGs. Specifically, I'm trying to render an SVG in an Android browser without the use of a library (ie. just using `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/logo.svg"></object>`, or something similar)

Is this possible across all browsers (iOS Safari, Android, WP7)? I'm specifically referring to mobile browsers at this point.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead. it will work in all browsers.

```
<iframe id="logo" src="images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" frameborder="0" onload="Init()" />;
```

it will allow you to access javascript functions or DOM elements of logo.svg from html page.

```
logo = document.getElementById("chart");
logo.contentWindow.RenderChart(chart1Data, r); //javascript function in logo.svg
```

This will work in all browsers.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and mark this as the answer if it works, thanks! Question though, what's that reference to Init() for? Is the JS below that supposed to be the contents of the function "Init"?